# Excel formula, INDEX MATCH MAX IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data in 3 columns & 17 Rows (F8:H35)
Column Headers are:
F= Offense score  /  G= Defensive score  /  H= Team Name

I want to show the team name from (H) with the Max Difference between Offense & Defense (F-G)

I was able to find the Max Difference with this formula:

```
=MAX(IF((F8:F35<>"")*(G8:G35<>""),F8:F35-G8:G35))
```

But how do I show the team name (H) ?
I tried:  Index Match Max If  but I'm getting too few arguments

Not Working:

```
=INDEX(H8:H35,MATCH(MAX(IF((F8:F35<>"")*(G8:G35<>""),F8:F35-G8:G35))*F8:H35))
```

I'm in over my head here, not sure if I'm close or really far off.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.  It's worth noting that this is a filter list, the row order changes, base on offensive score (F).

Comment: 2 questions: `1)` are you looking for maximum *positive* difference between F and G, or just maximum difference *(either positive or negative)* between F and G? `2)` are the team names unique, and what would you like to return if there are more than one team have the maximum difference?

Answer (score 0):

This array formula appears to work

```
=INDEX(H8:H35,MATCH(MAX(IF((F8:F35<>"")*(G8:G35<>""),F8:F35-G8:G35)),F8:F35-G8:G35,0))
```

Would be easier though if you added a helper column showing the difference.

Comment: YOU DID IT!!    Thank you so much.  I was just about pulling my hair out.   Thank you, Thank you, Thank you

Comment: My pleasure. The bit you were missing was finding the position of the max difference.